# A Subversion Configurition

Tags: svn, centos

if I open my SVN http://localhost/repos/XXX
The browser says :

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /repos/XXX on this server.
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80

CENTOS 5.7 new installation (X64)

I am sure that all of the steps (http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_5&p=subversion) is run and no erros displayed.

---

This is my config:

```
cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf 

LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

#
# Example configuration to enable HTTP access for a directory
# containing Subversion repositories, "/var/www/svn".  Each repository
# must be readable and writable by the 'apache' user.  Note that if
# SELinux is enabled, the repositories must be labelled with a context
# which httpd can write to; this will happen by default for
# directories created in /var/www.  Use "restorecon -R /var/www/svn"
# to label the repositories if upgrading from a previous release.
#

#
# To create a new repository "http://localhost/repos/stuff" using
# this configuration, run as root:
#
#   # cd /var/www/svn
#   # svnadmin create stuff   
#   # chown -R apache.apache stuff
#

<Location /repos>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
#
#   # Limit write permission to list of valid users.
   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
#      # Require SSL connection for password protection.
      # SSLRequireSSL
#
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Authorization Realm"
     AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd
      # specify access control file
     AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svnusers
     Require valid-user
   </LimitExcept>
</Location>

EDIT：
    [root@ORA /]# ls -la /var/www/svn/XXX
    total 32
    drwxr-xr-x 6 apache apache 4096 Feb 24 09:53 .
    drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Feb 24 09:53 ..
    drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Feb 24 09:53 conf
    drwxr-sr-x 6 apache apache 4096 Feb 24 09:53 db
    -r--r--r-- 1 apache apache    2 Feb 24 09:53 format
    drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Feb 24 09:53 hooks
    drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Feb 24 09:53 locks
    -rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  229 Feb 24 09:53 README.txt
EDIT：
    ＃cat access_log

    127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2012:09:54:54 +0800] "GET /repos/XXX HTTP/1.1" 403 287 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.26) Gecko/20120216 CentOS/3.6-1.el5.centos Firefox/3.6.26"
```

Comment: `ls -la  /var/www/svn/XXX/`, pls. And error.log part

Comment: I have edited the topic. ls and log is at bottom.@LazyBadger Thx^^

Comment: Just note. SVN-Book, in "httpd, the Apache HTTP server" chapter's "Authorization Options" section define Limit as `  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>` **only**

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "only" , How can i solve it? @LazyBadger

Comment: I wrote corrected limit (1 line moved) in answer

Comment: And what about /etc/svnusers content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Location /repos>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
#
#      # Require SSL connection for password protection.
      # SSLRequireSSL
#
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Authorization Realm"
     AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd
      # specify access control file
     AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svnusers
#   # Limit write permission to list of valid users.
   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
     Require valid-user
   </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Comment: Revision 0: / This Just Require valid-user is OK @Lazy Badger

Comment: 1.svn co http://localhost/repos/XXX
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://localhost/repos/XXX' 
2.The browser and SVN client do not ask me User/Pass
(I am using ur config)

@Lazy Badger

Comment: OK. disable for test LimitExcept, add `Satisfy any` before `Require valid-user`... Well, 403 here means somehow bad permissions. LimitExcept can return back

Comment: [root@ORA ~]# svn co http://localhost/repos/XXX
Checked out revision 0.
Satisfy any = OK

But I want to ask Why the browser do not ask me USER/PASS in ACL mode? @Lazy Badger

Comment: because (with Satisfy any) anonymous checkout is allowed, only commit must be authentificated

Comment: I think I have solved the problem with your help. I just del all about Limit-Except chap. the system is OK. Thank you @Lazy Badger

Answer (score 0):

Try using SVNPath instead of SVNParentPath.

Answer (score 0):

## change SVNParentPath to SVNPath if you have only one repo in  list

SVNParentPath /var/www/svn --> SVNPath /var/www/svn